# How to find 3rd coodinates of a triangle if two coordinates and distances between the points are known?

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

Assume a simple graph, having a triangle in it. The points are $A, B$ and $C$.  I know points $A(x,y)$, $B(x,y)$ and the distances between $A$, $B$ and $C$. I want to get the coordinates of $C(x,y)$.

Eg :-  $A(x,y) = A(30,30)$, $B(x,y) = B(90,30)$. The distance between $A$ and $B$ is $60~\text{cm}$, $A$ and $C$ is $50~\text{cm}$ and $B$ and $C$ is $50~\text{cm}$. How to find $C(x,y)$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that point $C$ is $50~\text{cm}$ from both points $A$ and $B$.

The locus of points that is $50~\text{cm}$ from $A$ is the circle with radius $50~\text{cm}$ centered at $A$, which is
$$(x - 30~\text{cm})^2 + (y - 30~\text{cm})^2 = (50~\text{cm})^2 \tag{1}$$
The locus of points that is $50~\text{cm}$ from $B$ is the circle with radius $50~\text{cm}$ centered at $B$, which is 
$$(x - 90~\text{cm})^2 + (y - 30~\text{cm})^2 = (50~\text{cm})^2 \tag{2}$$
Point $C$ must be located at one of the two points where these two circles intersect.

[image: intersecting_circles]

By subtracting equation 2 from equation 1, you can solve for the $x$-coordinate of $C$.  You can then substitute your result into equation 1 or equation 2 to find the possible $y$-coordinates of $C$, of which there are two.

The two solutions to this problem are the points $(60, 70)$ and $(60, -10)$.

[image: intersecting_circle_with_equal_radii]

In the comments, you asked about solving the same problem for the points $A(20, 20)$, $B(60, 20)$ with $AB = 40$, $AC = 30$, and $BC = 60$.

To obtain the coordinates of point $C$, you need to solve the system of equations
\begin{align*}
(x - 20)^2 + (y - 20)^2 & = 30^2\\
(x - 60)^2 + (y - 20)^2 & = 60^2
\end{align*}
You should obtain the points $(6.25, 46.66)$ and $(6.25, -6.66)$, where the $y$-coordinates are approximate.

[image: intersecting_circles_with_different_radii]

Comment: Can i apply the same when the values are A(20,20) , B(60,20), and AB=40, BC=60 and AC=20 ?

Comment: It is not possible for a triangle to have side lengths of $20$, $40$, and $60$ since the sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle must exceed the length of the third side.  If you made $BC = 50$, you could use the same method.  The calculations would not be as easy.

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong.

Comment: AB =40, BC =60 and AC =30.

Comment: Yes, you could use the same method I used above.  Since $AC = 30$, you would obtain the equation $(x - 20)^2 + (y - 20)^2 = 30^2$.  Since $BC = 60$, you would obtain the equation $(x - 60)^2 + (y - 20)^2 = 60^2$.  You could then solve for the $x$-coordinate of point $C$ by subtracting the second equation from the first, then use your result to determine the possible values of the $y$-coordinates.

Comment: I applied the same equation here, but I am getting x=5/8 . But in graph x approximately equals 3 :-(

Comment: I get \begin{align*} (x - 20)^2 - (x - 60)^2 & = 30^2 - 60^2\\ x^2 - 40x + 400 - (x^2 - 120x + 3600) & = 900 - 3600\\ 80x - 3200 & = -2700\\ 80x & = 500\\ x & = \frac{50}{8}\\ x & = 6.75 \end{align*}

Comment: When i tried to to draw the triangle in the graph, x and y appears to be almost like 3 and 5 ,ie, C(3,5)

Comment: I made a mistake in my final step.  I should have written $x = 6.25$, from which I get $y \approx 46.66$ or $x \approx -6.66$.  You can verify that these numbers satisfy both equations.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your whatsapp number?

Comment: I do not have one.  The answers to the question you originally posed were $(60, 70)$ and $(60, -10)$.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. C(60,70)is  what I get from grpah. But that triangle has some property . I think i cant apply the same equation for the second triangle

Comment: You can apply the same method in both cases.  I have added diagrams which confirm my answers.

Comment: Thank you sir, do you have any idea solvong this type of problems by programming (any such as c, c++, java etc? ) Any source code available?

Comment: My area of expertise is mathematics rather than programming.  Have you tried using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)?